# Could we recognise if time was running at a different rate for one species than another? I.e a human and an ant

Tags: biophysics, observers, perception, time

My question is quite simple if time ran at a different speed for smaller creatures, how would we be able to observe this or confirm by experiment?

Comment: Do you mean their psychological time? That for instance ant would subjectively recognize our second as a very long time interval? Or you mean that small clocks would run at different rate?

Comment: I mean physiologically i.e. the real passage of time for both entities being different. However I think my question has been answered satisfactorily below.

Answer (score 0):

Well technically speaking, time (or better say passage of time) is identical in two frames of reference that are not accelerating with respect to one another (i.e. at rest or moving at constant speed).

So yeah, if an ant and an elephant are put on a missile and accelerated into outer space and back, they would have aged identically with respect to one another, but both would have aged less than all of us here on Earth.

If by time you mean "perception" of time, then that is a very different question and would have to do with metabolism and the way brains process information. For example it is known that small insects, like flies, can process light flickering as much as 4 times faster than us (much higher frame rate in digesting visual information) and thus it looks as if they see the world in slow-motion. Though to them it looks like humans are incredibly slow and lazy; the way we see sloths :)

Comment: I accept the above. I'm not sure if my next point is relevant, however what happens if we extent the size of the two objects till they start to have their own gravitational field and separate them. They are not accelerating away from each other and their mass is substantially different. Would the passage of time run at a different rate now ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to interpret *time* in this context (and my list is probably not complete):

- *speed of physical processes* (which is obviously the same in a human and in an ant)
- *speed of chemical processes*, i.e., the speed of metabolism - this is specific to organism, since the speed of the relevant physical and chemical processes (such as diffusion time, reaction rates) depends on the organism-specific chemicals, sizes, temperature, genome and protein lengths, etc.
- *perception of time* - this is likely different, but hard to define regorously, since it implies a degree of consciousness - a rather slippery subject when discussing non-humans.
- *evolutionary time* is usually measured in generations or the rate of mutations or substitutions in the genome (see [molecular clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_clock)). These are specific to species (but not always applicable to individual organisms).

Comment: Just for a while play along with me. Let’s suppose that your first answer ‘speed of physical processes’ is not the same. Would there be any practical or experimental way of proving this is the case ?

Comment: @Harvey speed of physical processes is determined by the interactions between the particles and molecules - they no nothing about what is made out of them. It had to do with fundamentals of physics - not with whether the system is biological or not. So it is better to ask a new question.

Answer (score -2):

Not all animals might be moving at the same speeds and seconds will be counted faster for faster animals so larger number of seconds might equal second

Comment: Welcome to physics stack exchange! - It's not really clear what your answer is getting at. Perhaps rephrase it as a thought experiment to illustrate your point more clearly.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.